# Scala list made of negative numbers

Tags: scala

Why this expression is valid

```
val nums = 1::2::3::4::1::1::5::Nil
```

but this is not?

```
val nums = 1::2::3::4::1::-1::5::Nil
```

I'm getting this error

Multiple markers at this line

- value :: is not a member of Int
- left- and right-associative operators with same precedence may not be mixed

Thanks

Comment: Put a parenthesis around `-1`, `val nums = 1::2::3::4::1::(-1)::5::Nil`

Comment: adding a space between cons (::) and negative symbol solves the issue. the compiler might mistake ::- as a single symbol

Comment: You should always use spaces like `val nums = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: 4 :: 1 :: -1 :: 5 :: Nil`